# Wrong position of global footer when used with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-navigation

My question is rather basic. I want to have a StackNavigator in a React Native app on top of a global footer.
This is the code of my base App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

class TestScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{}}>
        <Text>
          Hello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello,
          WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello,
          WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello,
          WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello,
          ...
          WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello,
          WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello,
          WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello,
          WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, WorldHello, World
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator(
 {
   Test: { screen: TestScreen }
 },
 {}
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
            <Stack />
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 50}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, it's a simple view containing one content view (containing the stack navigator), and an orange footer view with a height of 50. My original app is more complicated, of course. The code is simplified to show the issue.
The problem is that the footer is displayed on top of the Stack component:

[image]

If I don't use the stack navigator, but TestScreen directly, everything works fine as expected:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
            <TestScreen />
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 50}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Could this be a bug in react-navigation or am I missing some flexbox magic here?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**
Have a look at createBottomTabNavigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html or https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html. They seem to be doing just what you ask for. You can define all of the routes and create the visual footer in just one place.

**This is my take on Navigators, please correct me if I'm wrong.**

The Navigator should not be used as a Component, it is much more abstract than that. It helps the the components in your App to find each other, connects the dots. The StackNavigator is a navigator which puts each connected view on top of the last, so that you can go back by just pressing the back button for example.

If you have created a stack navigator 'Stack' with multiple Screens you can use it in your App class: `return(<Stack />)`. You don't need anything else. Now the first Screen you put in your stack navigator will be shown first, and it can reach any other of the screens: `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')}`.

So the Navigator is much more abstract than a View, and you should create a View seperatly that utilizes the navigator rather than using it directly as a Component. Example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from "react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo'
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

class Footer extends Component {
  render() {

    console.log(this.props.navigation)
    const { active, navigation } = this.props;
    const currentScreen = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          padding: 10,
          paddingHorizontal: 40,
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          alignItems: 'center',
          marginBottom: 0,
          height: '10%',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.15)',
          flexDirection: 'row'
        }}>

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen1')}>
          <Icon name='list' size={20} color={ currentScreen === 'Screen1' ? 'black' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2')}>
          <Icon name='add-to-list' size={20} color={ currentScreen === 'Screen2' ? 'black' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen3')}>
          <Icon name='add-to-list' size={20} color={ currentScreen === 'Screen3' ? 'black' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen4')}>
          <Icon name='add-to-list' size={20} color={ currentScreen === 'Screen4' ? 'black' : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export class Screen1 extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>
            Screen 1
        </Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class Screen2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>
            Screen 2
        </Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class Screen3 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>
            Screen 3
        </Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class Screen4 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>
            Screen 4
        </Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen1,
    Screen2,
    Screen3,
    Screen4      }
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stack />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I wanted to avoid adding the same footer in each one of my components over and over again. It would just be way simpler to have a global footer (and header) in a container component. Maybe that's not possible though.
I just saw that others tried this as well, and it seems to have worked for them:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/456

Comment: I get it! There might be a way, but people that I've seen having had a external and custom Header has always added it to each component (this way they can give it different props so that it looks different depending on what they tell it). Still you can make it less than I first suggested, have updated my answer so that it removes as much of duplicate code as possible.